# Get sum of numbers using a Function and For Loop

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I want to define a function, `sumAll(n)` that `sums all numbers from 1 to n`.

For example, when I call `sumAll(10)` should return the `answer 55`...

Because:

```
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10 = 55
```

The function `sumAll` needs to use a for loop to carry out this summation, and it will have to use a sum variable that increases in value over each iteration of the for loop.

I have a working function that does not use a for loop, but I need to know how to use a for loop to accomplish this as well.

Here is the working program:

```
def sumAll(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0

    return n + sumAll(n - 1)

number = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: \n"))

print ("The answer is: ") + str(sumAll(number))
```

How do I use a "for" loop to accomplish this?
Am I right in assuming the `"for loop"` should be nested in the `"sumAll"` function?

I have tried many times to do this using a for loop and I keep getting a `infinite result and errors`...

Here is my code:

```
def sumAll(n):
    y = n + sumAll(n -1)
    return y

num = int(raw_input("Please enter a number")
for n in range(num):
    num = sumAll(num)
    print num
```

Comment: Have you tried using `sum()`? Or anything involving a `for` loop?

Comment: Please see [The Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) for examples of [```for```](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) statement usage.

Comment: You seriously came up with a working recursion solution for this, complete with a base case, but you don't know how to add the numbers 1-10 in a for loop??

Comment: When you tried "many times", did you save ANY of those tries? Could you include one of these tries?

Comment: `return n * (n + 1) / 2`

Comment: Please excuse, this is a working program of an answer I found on this site. I am still very new to python, so thats why am I asking. I can't find an answer that tells me how to use a for loop to solve this type of problem. The code is more to give you guys reference to what I mean.

Comment: read a basic for loop example, I honestly think you'll be able to figure it out.

Comment: And in the long run, you'll help yourself better by figuring out this answer than copy/pasting it from Stack....

Comment: Hint: a recursive function must have at least one code path where it does not call itself. ex. the working code won't call itself when n is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `for loop`

```
def sumAll(n):
    sum_all = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        sum_all = sum_all + i
    return sum_all

number = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: \n"))

print ("The answer is: ") + str(sumAll(number))
```

Output:

```
Please enter a number: 
10
The answer is: 55
```

You can also use [list Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
print sum([i for i in range(number+1)])
```

Output:

```
55
```

You can also use a mathematical series formula:

```
def sumAll(n):
    return n * (n + 1) / 2
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question. They want to do this in a function.

Comment: No, this still isn't what OP was asking for.

Comment: @MorganThrapp  It's okk ??

Comment: Thank you for the answer S_A,  it was exactly what I needed. I apologise for the down vote, I don't understand it either because it was really helpful, thanks.

Comment: I have, but unfortunately because of all the down votes on my question, I cannot uproot anymore, only mark that the answer was wat I needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can even do it without a loop:

```
def sumAll(n):
    return  sum(range(1,n+1))

print(sumAll(10)) # -> 55
```

if you insist on using a loop:

```
def sumAll(n):
    s = 0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        s += i
    return s
```

but the mathematical solution is simply:

```
def sumAll(n):
    return n * (n + 1) / 2  
    # in python 3:
    # return n * (n + 1) // 2
```

(there are `n` elements with an average value of `(n+1)/2`; this will always be an integer since either `n` or `n+1` is even; the proof by induction is often the first example when math students learn about induction...).

Answer (score 0):

You will get an error with sum(1, 2, 3, 4)
TypeError: sum expected at most 2 arguments, got 4

```
sum((1, 2, 3, 4)) # works cuz tuple inside
sum([1, 2, 3, 4]) # works cuz list inside
```

so the func will need to gather elements into a tuple, e.g.

```
numbers = 1, 2, 3, 4
print(sum(numbers)) # already a tuple so works
```

use * with your parameter to gather the caller's args into a tuple. 
* enabbles any-number of args to be supplied by caller and they are converted into a tuple parameter.

```
def sumall(*args):
    return sum(args)
print(sumall(1))
print(sumall(1, 2))
print(sumall(1, 2, 3))
print(sumall(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

produces the expected answers. Credit: author Downey asks for this exercises solution in chapter 12 of Think Python (2016)